# Отступ сверху и снизу

Tags: отступы, html, вёрстка, css

Уже 3 часа сижу ищу, откуда вылез отступ (вверху как будто body отступает на 12пх), откуда он?

[Вот код](http://jsfiddle.net/v0m2mka6/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Может, это поможет 
 + у вас высота жестко стоит:

`#header_top { height: 170px;}`

И не только здесь.

Comment: не помогло...:( если меняю высоту #sidebar_top_bgg например в 0 то все становится как надо...Но мне же нужно что б он отображался в полном виде

Comment: а если высоту поставить height: auto

Comment: Вобщем я к боди задал бг центр..поетому все тянулось..жесть